# How can I make single control field to control multiple columns in Google Data Studio?

Tags: controls, looker-studio

I like to make a single control field, such as dropdown-list, to control multiple columns with the same value. As the sample link(1) below in Google Sheet. My raw data, consist of the type of anesthesia, the name of the nurse during surgery.

This sheet "RR" consist of raw data, then I make a new table using some functions, to look like sheet "LogBook".

If I choose name of the nurse for example "Wayan", then it will count each part of surgery and type of anesthesia that Wayan had been involved, and it will count the type of surgery also.

When I use Google Data Studio, I can only make single control field  for example "Nurse in pre surgery", "Nurse in intra surgery", or "Nurse in post surgery". Or if I select all of the control fields, then it become "AND", that's not what I want. I want to make a single control like "Name of the nurse", then google data studio, will show like the one in Google Sheet.

The table in Google Data Studio, show same value for all columns, which is wrong. The data in Google Sheets is the right one (which is using [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) function).

**Inputs**:

- [LogBook in GoogleSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vt3XgIdJkG1c-Q2KNnqUeYo1Lw-SUKaCpwuSYwqo69I/edit?usp=sharing)
- [LogBook in Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f73ae5b7-00f4-4b7d-a233-6e11cf04d017)

**Images**:
This is the raw data in Google Sheet "RR":
[image]

This is how the data should be shown in Google Data Studio:
[image]

But Google Data Studio does not allow me to use 1 control field, to control multiple columns:
[image]

If I select same value in all of control fields, then it become "AND" relation, which is wrong:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) the three fields (`Nurse in Pre Surgery`, `Nurse in Intra Surgery` and `Nurse in Post Surgery`) to create a single new field with CSV (Comma Separated Values). The [CSV Filter Control](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/2b0a22a2-3992-49e1-be12-bdc22937daea/page/QPvLB) [Community Visualisation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527) (click on the [image: 4] icon on the toolbar and select [image: 5] to view all) can then be used to filter by nurse:

**Data Tab**

- ***Column to filter on***:

  ```
  CONCAT(Nurse in Pre Surgery, ", ", Nurse in Intra Surgery, ", ", Nurse in Post Surgery)
  ```
- ***Cross-filtering***: Select (☑) (selection will ensure that filtering will be applied to other charts)

**Style Tab**

- ***OR instead of AND behaviour***: Select (☑) (tick so that data for multiple nurses can be viewed, when selected)

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/90311f9e-be2f-4d60-a1d6-56769b02b354) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jDP4OBxzDK-fVDtymobVlWRc7wPGo65_1RGNOOQvKCE/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 8]