# How can I combine two data columns being used as separate filter controls into one single filter control without losing any values or data?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

**Question:** How can I combine two data columns being used as separate filter controls into one single filter control without losing any values in Google Data Studio?

- I have attempted to use a calculated field of "**Coalesce([column1],[column 2])**". This works mostly, however, sometimes values in the two columns are different and I am losing a few values that need to be included in the list.
- I am pulling data from BigQuery using a custom query. The two columns have different names, but have the same data type (text). Both columns are a part of the same table/data set
- I cannot list the specific values in this post because of data sensitivity, however I've included an example below.
- Sometimes when the columns are viewed side by side, one column contains a null value, OR both values could be the same, OR both values could be different

**Example**

| Column A |
| --- |
| ABCDE |
| FGHIJ |
| KLMNO |
| GGGG |

| Column B |
| --- |
| PQRS |
| TUVW |
| XYZA |
| GGGG |

**Side by Side View - This is what the data looks like in tabular form:**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| null | ABCDE |
| PQRS | FGHIJ |
| TUVW | null |
| XYZA | KLMNO |
| GGGG | GGGG |

The coalesce function does not work because I am losing values where the two columns have different values - **Coalesced Filter List will only include:**

- ABCDE
- PQRS
- TUVW
- XYZA
- GGGG

**Missing Values:**

- FGHIJ
- KLMNO

**Filter List Should Be:**

- ABCDE
- PQRS
- TUVW
- XYZA
- GGGG
- FGHIJ
- KLMNO

**Question Reiterated:** I want to combine these two columns as one list to be used in a single filter dropdown in Google Data Studio without losing values.

**Sample Data**:

- Data Set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kh_WOUQK4V9fgiB-mYdAMN6xnBe8hcLgImTOTHuH4e8/edit?usp=sharing))
- [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5c9e9a6b-df83-43a5-8a84-9151692c8525) report

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution below is similar to the suggestion in the question [How can I make single control field to control multiple columns in Google Data Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71286227), where the [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) function is used to join multiple fields (in this question, two fields titled `Column A` and `Column B`, respectively) by creating a single CSV (comma-separated values) field so that the [CSV Filter Control](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/2b0a22a2-3992-49e1-be12-bdc22937daea/page/QPvLB) [Community Visualisation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9206527) can be used to display and filter the required value(s); the difference being the possibility of NULL values in the fields:

#### Setup Tab

- ***Column to filter on***:

  ```
  CASE
    WHEN Column A IS NULL AND Column B IS NOT NULL THEN Column B
    WHEN Column A IS NOT NULL AND Column B IS NULL THEN Column A
    WHEN Column A IS NOT NULL AND Column B IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(Column A, ",", Column B)
    ELSE NULL
  END
  ```
- ***Cross-filtering***: Select (☑) (this makes sure that filtering values will apply to all charts)

#### Style Tab

- ***OR instead of AND behaviour***: Select (☑) (data for multiple values in `Column A` or `Column B` can be viewed, when clicked)

Note that the [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) above can be shortened, for example, the first `WHEN`:

`WHEN Column A IS NULL AND Column B IS NOT NULL THEN Column B`

could be:

`WHEN Column A IS NULL THEN Column B`

However, the purpose of the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) is to ensure that a single field (no support fields required) is created that also serves as [self-documenting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code), where each `WHEN` clause is clearly understood by the editor or viewer, as all three `WHEN` clauses are consistent, where the exact criteria is specified for `Column A` and `Column B` in all three instances.

Subsequently, the `ELSE NULL` in this scenario, serves the purpose of:

`WHEN Column A IS NULL AND Column B IS NULL THEN NULL`

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/db71e1dc-682c-4603-9a0c-f1fe0c28b612) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PmranH1TQzSxdGYtjeuKdUnboghUx4pnsGxMQ9DsmYs/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]

Answer (score 0):

> I am pulling data from BigQuery using a custom query

Use below as a custom query

```
select distinct col
from your_table, unnest([ColumnA, ColumnB]) col
where not col is null
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]